# Plugin uninstall: why run dbDelta after $wpdb->query($drop_sql)

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

i am reading professional wordpress. their code for uninstalling a plugin is

```
//build our query to delete our custom table
$sql = "DROP TABLE " . $table_name . ";";

//execute the query deleting the table
$wpdb->query($sql);
require_once(ABSPATH .’wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php’);
dbDelta($sql);
```

my question is why run `dbDelta` after `$wpdb->query($sql);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed bizarre. I think they first tried it with `dbDelta`, found it doesn't work with `DROP` queries, and went with a straight `$wpdb` query instead. They then just forgot to take out the `dbDelta` stuff. It appears `dbDelta` collects creation queries in `$cqueries` and insert queries in `$iqueries`, but [silently ignores the rest](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L1393). What a lovely function...

To be sure, you could ask this question on [the book forum](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-wordpress-567/), hopefully the authors hang around there. Don't forget to mention you first asked it here, so we get some publicity!

Comment: I noticed this too. I see you didn't get an answer on the book forum either :-(