# How does uninstalling WordPress plugins work?

Tags: plugin-development, uninstallation

I'm trying to drop a database table when the user uninstalls the plugin. But what does uninstalling a WordPress plugin really mean?

There's the deactivation hook and there's also the uninstall hook. And then there's the `uninstall.php` file.

On the constructor of the plugin class I have the uninstall hook:

```
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'uninstall_housekeeping'));
```

Then the `uninstall_housekeeping` method has the following code:

```
public function uninstall_housekeeping(){

global $wpdb;
$tweets_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'zam_tweets';

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
dbDelta("DROP TABLE $tweets_table");
}
```

According to the wordpress codex you need to have an `uninstall.php` file which contains the code that will execute when the plugin is uninstalled so I also put this code:

```
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
exit();
global $wpdb;
$tweets_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'zam_tweets';

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
dbDelta("DROP TABLE $tweets_table");
```

But all I can see on the WordPress plugin page is the `activate` and `delete` links when the plugin is currently deactivated. And then the `deactivate` and `edit` link if its currently active. **Where's `uninstall`?** I already tried the delete link but it doesn't seem like its doing anything except to delete the whole plugin folder, the database table is still intact.

Comment: What is that `dbDelta`? Why not use `$wpdb`? And that `require_once` is kind of strange to be there... What if you try a `delete_option` just to confirm `uninstall.php` is working ok. Well, it *does work ok*, the problem is in your code. **\[edit\]** The [first link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1643/12615) here in the Related sidebar explains that `dbDelta` and the correct use of the drop table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment in the Question, the error is certainly in how the `DROP TABLE` is being performed. But answering to *How does uninstalling WordPress plugins work?*:

If we do a `register_uninstall_hook` in our plugin, the callback is stored in the option `uninstall_plugins` in [`/wp-includes/plugin.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/plugin.php#L677).

```
$uninstallable_plugins[plugin_basename($file)] = $callback;
update_option('uninstall_plugins', $uninstallable_plugins);
```

In the PHPDoc for the function `register_uninstall_hook` we have this:

> This file *(uninstall.php)* will be called, if it exists, during the uninstall process bypassing the uninstall hook.

And the bypass happens in [`/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L839):

```
define('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN', $file);
include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . dirname($file) . '/uninstall.php';
return true;
```

So, whatever you have in the uninstall hook or file, it should work by its own. If it does, ***it will work*** when the uninstall happens.