# How do I reset BackWPup?

Tags: plugins

I recently installed the BackWPup plugin to my site, and it has been working fine, until recently when I changed servers, now it doesn't backup.  I'm wondering if this is because I changed servers it perhaps have old information.
Can you tell me if I need to reset BackWPup?
If the answer is yes, how do I reset this?
Do  need to deactivate?

Thanks for your help.

Annette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, deactivating is not enough. A well coded plugin will normally delete its options/files [when it is uninstalled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100763/12615).

Others, as an extra feature may offer this clean-up in its own page, but that's not common.
So, you'll need to deactivate, delete and install again.

This can be short-circuited inspecting the plugin's `register_uninstall_hook` or `uninstall.php` file, and executing the needed actions by your own.

In BackWPUp case, it's done via file, not hook. And in `uninstall.php` [we can see](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/backwpup/tags/3.0.12/uninstall.php) that the following MySQL query is needed:

```
"DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->options . " WHERE option_name LIKE '%backwpup_%' "
```

`$wpdb->options` corresponds to your `wp_prefix_options` table. This is for a normal WP install, if you're running a Multisite, the table is `$wpdb->sitemeta`.

To test it out, run first in PHPMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%backwpup_%'
```

and then proceed to:

```
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%backwpup_%'
```